# Event delegation much faster in Firefox and Opera, how come? [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, event-delegation

I've got a huge table (like a few thousand rows), and when I click a row, I do something simple like changing the color of the row.
The problem is, when I click a row, it takes a really long time (1 second) to change the color. I see this in Chrome and Safari. But when I try it in Firefox or Opera, it's supersnappy.

I thought event delegation (instead of binding an event listener to each row, a parent div takes care of all events) would fix it, but no, it remains te same.

Any help?

Comment: It would help if we could see some code. You are right in thinking that delegating the event handler should help though.

Comment: Maybe it's just the rendering engine that's making the difference.

Comment: [Repaints](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) and how to [benchmark/test](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-repaint) them as this could be the reason of this phenomenon

Comment: You're right. It's the repainting, which is especially slow with tables. The problem is it can't be done without a table :(.
So I guess there's no solution? Thanks anyway!